# $\exists n$ such that $3M \geq \left|\frac {f(x+ \frac {y-x} ni )-f(x+ \frac {y-x} n (i-1)) } {\frac {y-x} n}\right|$ for each $1 \leq i \leq n$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continous.

Assume $-M \leq \underline Df(x) \leq \overline Df(x) \leq M$ on $[a,b].$

We are using the notation in *Royden & Fitzpatrick*:
$$
\begin{split}
\overline Df(x)&:=\lim_{h \to 0^+} \sup\left\{\frac {f(x+t)-f(x)} t:0<|t|<h\right\}\\
\underline Df(x)&:=\lim_{h \to 0^+} \inf\left\{\frac {f(x+t)-f(x)} t:0<|t|<h\right\}
\end{split}
$$

> **Q:** Is it true that there exists some positive integer $n$ such that, for each, $1 \leq i \leq n$, we have 
>   $$
> 3M \geq \left|\frac {f\big(x+ \frac {y-x} ni \big)-f\big(x+ \frac {y-x} n (i-1)\big) } {\frac {y-x} n}\right|\;?
> $$
>   I am not 100% sure, but I think the answer to to the highlighted question is "yes." (In which case, it would be a helpful lemma for me to prove something more significant.)

Naively, the first thought is to take a sort of "limit" so we could say something about the quantity 
$$
\left|\frac{f\big(x+ \frac {y-x} ni \big)-f\big(x+ \frac {y-x} n (i-1)\big) } {\frac {y-x} n}\right|
$$ as $n \to \infty$, comparing it to the upper and lower Dini derivatives which are bounded by $M$. However, the order of quantifiers makes $i$ dependent on $n$ so I am having trouble making this rigorous.

I also haven't yet taken advantage of the assumption that $f$ is continous, so perhaps continuity helps somewhow?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, $-M \le \underline Df(x) \le \overline Df(x) \le M$ on $[a, b]$ implies that $f$ is [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) on $[a, b]$ with modulus $M$.  This immediately implies your desired inequality for all $n$ and $i$, with the bound strengthened from $3M$ to $M$.

*Proof:* Let $a \le x < y \le b$ and define $k = \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x}$, $S = \left\{z \in (x, b] \middle\bracevert \frac{f(z) - f(x)}{z - x} \ge k\right\}$. Since $S$ contains $y$, it has an infimum $w \in [x, b]$.

- If $w \notin S$, then there are $z \in (w, y)$ arbitrarily close to $w$ with $z \in S$, hence $\frac{f(z) - f(w)}{z - w} \ge k$.
- If $w \in S$, then there are $z \in (x, w)$ arbitrarily close to $w$ with $z \notin S$, hence $\frac{f(z) - f(w)}{z - w} \ge k$.

Therefore, $k \le \overline Df(w) \le M$.  Similarly, $k \ge \underline Df(w) \ge -M$.